# Running a Script by using Rasa's Custom Actions and rendering an Image

Tags: chatbot, rasa-core, rasa

I had been trying to run a data science script while using the custom actions of Rasa chatbot framework. Below is the class through which I'm executing this custom action

```
class ActionPlotGraph(Action):

    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_plot_returns"

    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
            tracker: Tracker,
            domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:
        data = web.DataReader('AAPL',data_source='yahoo',start='01/01/2018', end ='01/01/2019')['Adj Close']
        if data:
            returns = data.pct_change()
            first = returns[1].string()
            ax = sns.lineplot(data= returns, x='Time', y= 'Returns')

        dispatcher.utter_message(text=first)

        return []
```

I had already imported all the dependency in python file. When I train and talk to chatbot which should trigger this, it gives out various errors. Questions:

1) Is something wrong with the code inside `ActionPlotGraph` class?

2) Is it the right method for running different codes inside Actions classes and returning particular values? Or we should keep the scripts separate?

Comment: What are you running/inputting to the bot, and what errors are you getting? It is hard to know what might be wrong without info about errors.